# Need a simple tutorial for android/webservice work?

Tags: android, xml, json, web-services, cordova

I'm really new working with Android, so there's a lot that's confusing me. I've looked at what seems like 100 tutorials and examples of how to get information from a web service on Android, but what I need is something for a guy that doesn't have a clue. Here are a couple of things in particular that I'm not getting:

- I don't know what to do with XML files.. meaning, once I do the Java work, is that all that needs to be done? or does anything need to be changed in the XML files?
- Seems like maybe I'm supposed to create a new class for some of these tutorials, but I'm not sure, and if so, I'm not sure what to do once I've made the class
- I want to retrieve the information in JSON format. For right now as long as I can get just that information that's fine, I can learn how to work with JSON later.
- It seems like kSoap2 is the best way to do this. I have the jar file that's needed to work with it
- I've delved a little into phonegap, so if there's an answer that uses that, then I can work with that

My web service is working properly, and is essentially the same as what I've seen in a number of tutorials, so there's no problem there.

If anyone can point me to a tutorial that will help me out to learn ALL that I need to know to create a sample app that gets information from my web service, or if anyone is willing to walk me through it, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Initially** you have to make an http connection so that you can get the response from your api be it xml response or json response. You can use the following code for it.
Keep the class separate than activity. :-

```
public class Response {

String get_url, response;
Activity activity;

public Response(String url){
    this.get_url = url;

}

public String getResponse(){
     InputStream in = null;        
      byte[] data = new byte[1000];
        try {
              URL url = new URL(get_url);   
              URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
              conn.connect();
            /*  conn.*/
              in = conn.getInputStream();
              Log.d("Buffer Size +++++++++++++", ""+in.toString().length());
              BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in),in.toString().length());
              String line;
              StringBuilder sb =  new StringBuilder();
              while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
              }
              rd.close();
              response = sb.toString();

             in.read(data);
          Log.d("INPUT STREAM PROFILE RESPONSE",response);
            in.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            Log.d("CONNECTION  ERROR", "+++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return response;
}
}
```

You may call the class in your activity like this :-

```
Response res = new Response("your_url");
String getResponse = res.getResponse();
```

So here you get the response from the api.

**Now Lets make the parser**

```
         //Extend the class with Default Handler

         public class XMLParser extends DefaultHandler {
              //You must have basic knowledge about Array List and setter/getter methods
              // This is where the data will be stored
       ArrayList<Item> itemsList;
          Item item;
           String data;
            String type;
           private String tempVal;

                 //Create the Constructor
           public XMLParser(String data){
        itemsList = new ArrayList<Item>();

        this.data = data;

    }

     public byte parse(){

            SAXParserFactory spf = null;
            SAXParser sp = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;

            try {
                inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data.getBytes());
                spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
                if (spf != null) {
                    sp = spf.newSAXParser();
                    sp.parse(inputStream, this);
                }
            }
            /*
             * Exceptions need to be handled MalformedURLException
             * ParserConfigurationException IOException SAXException
             */

            catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                try {
                    if (inputStream != null)
                        inputStream.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }

            if (itemsList != null && itemsList.size() > 0) {
            //  //Log.d("Array List Size",""+tipsList.get(4).getTitle());


                return 1;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }

        }

     public ArrayList<Item> getItemList(){
         return itemsList;
     }


              // Here you can check for the xml Tags
     @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName,
            Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {


         if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
             item = new Item();
             Log.d("Working", "+++++++++++++++++++++++");
         }


     }
         //tempVal is the variable which stores text temporarily and you
                 // may save the data in arraylists
     public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)
                throws SAXException {
            tempVal = new String(ch, start, length);
        }


     @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName)
            throws SAXException {




         if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
             itemsList.add(item);
             Log.d("Working in endelement", "+++++++++++++++++++++++");

            item.setTitle(tempVal);

        }
       }
```

**Combining all this :-**

Now lets see the activity

```
         public void oncreate(){
               // Do something or mostly the basic code
               // Call the class to initate the connection and get the data
                 FetchList fl = new FetchList();
                  fl.execute();
                  }
          //Always better to use async task for these purposes
           public class FetchList extends asyncTask<Void,Void,Byte>{

                doinbackground{
                    // this was explained in first step
                     Response res = new Response("url");
                     String response = res.getResponse();
                     XmlParser xml = new XmlParser(response);
                      ArrayList<item> itemList = xml.getItemList();
                      xml.parse();
                 }
                }
```

Well that is all to it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

So, to make sure I've got this right...

I make a new java class called Response, then call Response in the activity java code. 
I see where you're combining it all, but where do I put the parser? And does anything go into main.xml or any other files for the output? Or will this be all I need to run the app?

Comment: if you see the doinbackground method it calls for response as you have understood correctly after that i am calling the XmlParser class and passing in the response which i got from my Response class. Main.xml is just to set the layout and to show the ui it has nothing to do with parsing. In order to show a list of items on the ui you would have to add a linearlayout in main.xml and create a custom view. Then after doinbackground you may use arraylist to create custom view and then add it in your linearlayout like layout.addView(CustomListItem) something like that