# Retrieving data from database

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am trying to retrieve specific data like custom ads, username, date etc from database. so followed the code from this [Need a simple tutorial for android/webservice work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520243/need-a-simple-tutorial-for-android-webservice-work). I'm going wrong some where can any one help as i am new to android.Getting following errors

```
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.response/com.response.FetchList}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.response.FetchList
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.response.FetchList
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-13 21:57:14.720: E/AndroidRuntime(399):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
```

**Edit-** 
 Manifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.response"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".Response"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_response" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity" />
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".XMLParser"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_response" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".FetchList"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_response" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Did you sign FetchList activity in manifest?

Comment: A think, this post look like this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4688277/java-lang-runtimeexception-unable-to-instantiate-activity-componentinfo

Comment: I have edited your question and added the Class code as you posted in the below answer. If there is something wrong, feel free to rollback.

Comment: How can i retrieve specific content which is present in my website to android app. How can i obtain data from server?

Comment: You want to show your database data on the listview or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've taken the code from that link exactly as-is, then you could be running into that error at the line,

```
public class FetchList extends asyncTask<Void,Void,Byte>{

                doinbackground{
```

Which would actually be

```
    public class FetchList extends asyncTask<Void, Void, Byte> {
        @Override
        protected Byte doInBackground (Void... voids){
          ...
        }
    }
```

**EDIT:** From the code in your comment,

```
public class FetchList extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Byte>{
  @Override
  protected Byte doInBackground1(Void... arg0){
        // this was explained in first step
        Response res = new Response("url");
        String response = res.getResponse();
        XMLParser xml = new XMLParser(response);
        ArrayList<XMLParser> itemList = xml.getItemList();
        return xml.parse();
  }
}
```

In this case let me know what the Logcat output is.

Comment: public class FetchList extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Byte>{

 protected Byte doInBackground1(Void... arg0){
        // this was explained in first step
         Response res = new Response("url");
         String response = res.getResponse();
         XMLParser xml = new XMLParser(response);
          ArrayList<XMLParser> itemList = xml.getItemList();
          return xml.parse();
     }

 @Override
 protected Byte doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  return null;
 }
}
 this is FetchList class when i run app its displaying force close

Comment: Why do you have 2 methods with the same name?
Remove the second instance of `doInBackGround()` in your code, and add the `@Override` signature above the first instance of that method.

Comment: You've marked the answer as accepted, so I'm assuming the problem is solved. If you're still getting errors, post them here.

Comment: In that case edit your question and add the message you get in Logcat when the app crashes. We'll try to help you out there too.